# Add month using MomentJS

Tags: momentjs

I'd like to add a month to my `currentDueDate` using MomentJS but it seems not working with days...

I want to keep the day when adding a month.

I want this :

1. 30/10/2015
2. 30/11/2015
3. 30/12/2015
4. 30/01/2016
5. 29/02/2016 (last day of the month when `30` is not in the month)
6. 30/03/2016

The code :

`currentDueDate.add(1, 'M');`

I get this :

1. 30/10/2015
2. 30/11/2015
3. 30/12/2015
4. 30/01/2016
5. 29/02/2016
6. 29/03/2016 (should be 30/03/2016)

Edit (the entire code):

```
  <!-- Calculs -->

  <% var currentDueDate = moment(agreement.billbook.first_due_date) || moment(); %>

  <% var nbLines = 6; %>
  <% var monthToAdd = 1; %>

  <!-- /Calculs -->

  <table class="table">        

    <% for(var i = 0; i < nbLines; i++ ){ %>

    <tr>
      <td><%=i+1%></td>
      <td><%=currentDueDate.format('L')%></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <% currentDueDate.add(monthToAdd, 'M'); %>

    <% } %>

  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, Date with days `29`,`30` and `31` are corner cases. Also, for day `31`, there is one more corner case as all months do not have 31 days. What I suggest is to have three `functions` to cover all the scenarios:

```
1) dateWith31
2) dateWith29And30
3) dateWithRest - has the same flow what you have wrote

switch currentDueDate.get('date') :
  case 31 :
    dateWith31(currentDueDate)
  case 30 :
    dateWith29And30(currentDueDate)
  case 29 :
    dateWith29And30(currentDueDate)
  default :
    dateWithRest(currentDueDate)



function dateWith31(currentDueDate){
  for(var i = 0; i < nbLines; i++ ){
    currentDueDate.add(1,'M').endOf('M');
  }
}

function dateWith29And30(currentDueDate){
  var temp = currentDueDate.get('date');  //stores the original day
  for(var i = 0; i < nbLines; i++ ){
    var prevMonth = currentDueDate.get('M');
    if(prevMonth === 1) //date has been changed in February and hence fix it
      currentDueDate.add(1,'M').set('date',temp);
    else
      currentDueDate.add(1,'M');
  }
}
```

Hopefully it can be implemented in the language you are using(I guess it is PHP)

Comment: I don't want to get the last days of the current month. I'm in a `forEach` so I want to keep the day of the date except when the next date (with month() + 1) don't have the day... If the date don't have the day we'll set the new day with the last day in the month...

Comment: @tonymx227 - your question doesn't show a foreach loop.  Please edit your question with a *complete* example.